# Python Numpy Select Dynamic statement from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to do the following,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ('Harry','Sally','Megan'), 'Age': (30, 31,'NN')})

a={'target':"Age2",'check':"==30",'iftrue':["Is"]}

condis=[
        df['Age'] a['check']
        ]

df[a['target']]= np.select(condis,a['iftrue'],default=" ")
print(df)
```

I am stuck at trying to convert the a['check'] parameter received as a string to a statement so this,

```
df['Age'] a['check']
```

should resolve/compile to

```
df['Age'] ==30
```

Could someone give me any ideas on how to achieve this? Maybe I am missing something very basic and simple here.

Thanks.

Comment: Your code has invalid python syntax. Would you check it again?

Comment: That is precisely because of the problem statement, it isn't resolving to a statement.

Comment: You *could* use an `eval` there, which is hacky and bad style, or use a proper `lambda`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval to convert string to condition:

```
check = "==30"
age = "20"
print(eval(age+check))
>>> False
```

But it's not recommended because eval is a function is to use very carefully as it can execute arbitrary code it cause security issue and is hard to debug

a more proper solution would be for example to have an argument for comparison operator and one for comparaison parameter:

```
check_op = np.equal
check_arg = 30
print(check_op(check_arg, 20)
>>> False
```